# WooCommerce - Product tags not correctly displayed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags

In WooCommerce I've tagged my products via a CSV import and it was successful.

However, sometimes when viewing the product dashboard the tags do not display for *some* items (total items are ~240). And clicking "edit" (or quick edit) on the item doesn't show the tags.

Looking in the `term_relationships` table for the specific products I can see the correct term ids in the `term_taxonomy_id` column.

I've tried reducing the number of items to display at once and it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Is there some sort of caching or limit when WooCommerce queries the product tags?

What can I try to troubleshoot the issue further?

This is hosted on WPEngine and I have no other caching plugins installed.

WordPress version: 6.3
WooCommerce version: 8.2.1
PHP: 8.2

Comment: Go to Woo settings -> status -> tools and recount the terms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that doesn't work.
Even if I open the tag page (E.g. https://DOMAIN.TLDwp-admin/edit.php?product_tag=THE_SLUG_IN_QUESTION&post_type=product) it lists all products but some with an empty "Tags" column. Very strange.

Comment: What would happen if you update/resave a product that is missing a tag ?

Comment: Opening one with missing tags and saving it (without changing anything) removes the tags. E.g., showing all tags (as per link above) has count 240, after saving it is 1 less, 239.

Comment: so in other words somewhere during the import its "adding" but not completing the "save" process during import so its somewhat connected with the tag and in the same time its not ? Maybe rerun import ? Also what would i do is double check my CSV file and see how many products should be with tag A  double check on website how many are there and if some product is missing then go back to CSV grab this product as new CSV and reimport and test if its importing properly. If it is then could be server related issue...

Comment: The saving is happening correctly because it is correctly assigned in the database and when viewing the specific tag's products (wp-admin/edit.php?product_tag=THE_SLUG) it does show up but the "Tags" column is empty. The product won't appear in product list for the tag if it wasn't saved correctly.